# Check table before delete a constraint

Tags: mysql, constraint, if-not-exists, drop-table

In SQL Server I used the following code to drop a table with a constraint:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('EMPLOYEES') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
         ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES DROP CONSTRAINT EMP_DEPT_FK
         DROP TABLE EMPLOYEES;
  END
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in Mysql?

Comment: Just to show how i managed to do it: i used this command: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEES; 
 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `information_schema` to check if the table exists but in MySQL there is a simpler method:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees ;
```

Comment: The `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` syntax is also supported in SQL Server 2016 onwards.

Comment: So Simple... i thought i couldn't just do that.  
 What seems strange to me is that mysql doesn't check for constraint before drop the table.  
 In sqlserver i have to delete constraint before dropping a table.  
 Anyway, thank you.

Comment: No, it checks and drops the constraints with the table. And if other tables have constraints that reference the one you drop, you'll get an error.

Comment: Does SQL Server ned to drop the constraints first before dropping a table? I can't test right now but I'd think otherwise.

Comment: No it doesn't. But it doesn't let you drop individual columns that are referenced by constraints.

Comment: Perhaps @andrea is confusing necessity to drop constraints in general with necessity to drop *foreign keys **referencing the table** you are about to drop*.

Comment: My necessity was to drop the table to perform a fresh install. Doing so i have the necessity to check before if the table already exists, and if so, drop the table and recreate it. To check if the table already exists i used to do that way in sqlserver. I was looking to find a way to do the same in mysql.